# Multi-column index vs. index on an array

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm new to databases and trying to learn PostgreSQL. My question is:

Is there a difference between

```
CREATE INDEX the_index ON the_table (column1, column2);
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX the_index ON the_table (ARRAY[column1, column2]);
```

?

Comment: Interesting question.  Why would you think they are similar?  The first creates an index with two keys.  The second creates an index with one key that happens to be an array.  They look really different to me, so I don't know why you would think to even ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) indexes here, the second index won't even work in PostgreSQL. That is because a B-tree index can only be defined on data that have a [linear ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).

You can imagine an index as a sorted list of entries pointing to the table.
In the case of a multi-column index, the entries will be sorted in a [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) fashion: First, according to `column1`, and then – within each group of equal `column1` – according to `column2`.

The index can be used for all queries where the **scanned index entries are next to each other** in the index:

```
... WHERE column1 = 'text' AND column2 = 42
... WHERE column1 < 'text'
... WHERE column1 = 'text' AND column1 > 42
```

The index cannot be used with queries where the scanned index entries are not next to each other:

```
... WHERE upper(column1) = 'TEXT'
... WHERE column2 = 42
... WHERE column1 || column2 = 'text42'
```

---

Indexes on arrays are an entirely different thing. For these, you would have to use the “GIN” access method:

```
CREATE INDEX the_index ON the_table USING gin (ARRAY[column1, column2]);
```

(This assumes that both columns have the same data type.)

Such an index can be used to speed up queries using the array operators `<@`, `@>`, `=` and `&&`, for example

```
... WHERE ARRAY[column1, column2] && ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Given that the `WHERE` clause above is quite contrived, I would say that such an index does not make much sense in most cases.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I was really confused about SQL and ARRAY. Now I get it!